# Chrome on Ubuntu - file upload always defaults to home folder

Tags: google-chrome, filemanager

Google Chrome, when I upload a file to any website, the file chooser always defaults to my Home folder. If I need to upload multiple files to the same site, it is a huge nuisance that the file chooser doesn't go to the last used location, which is how I think it used to behave. I don't know when or why this changed.

Is there any way to set the behaviour to 'last used location' rather than always default to Home? Firefox, by contrast, always defaults to Desktop. Thunderbird goes to last used location. Therefore I guess this is a Chrome issue, however the posts on the Google forum are useless and I figured someone here would know. Thanks!

Comment: This is quite annoying. Now it defaults to "recent" which is useless...